# Add two languages in one <p>

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph on a WordPress site that contains two languages, what I need is to display each language in a different font-family (font-face)

Example:

```
<p>למרות הכל its worth it</p>
```

I've tried to insert span tags and div's, but it changed all of the sentence.

I tried this:

```
html:lang(en) h3{
font-family: Helvetica !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you know of classes / ID's and general CSS?

Comment: can you show what it looks like with the `span` tags? Span tags would work if it is static text. You may need to edit CSS to fit with the span attribute CSS-rule hierarchy.

Comment: it's not a big problem - try something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/axbq8rz1/

Comment: Yes i know i tried the LANG tag too but nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use some markup to explicitly set the language, like

```
<p><span lang="xyz">למרות הכל</span> <span lang="abc">its worth it</span></p>
```

After that you may use some basic CSS like:

```
[lang=xyz] {
    font-family: Arial;
}

[lang=abc] {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

or something like this:

```
span:lang(xyz) {
    font-family: Arial;
}

span:lang(abc) {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex3z8jgu/).

Hint: You should also use the correct [language code](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp), as this would also improve your content semantically and help search engines and screen readers to better understand it. [Read about the lang attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_lang.asp) in general.

Comment: Beat me to it, worth noting that actually `span:lang(xyz) {` will also work

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ Nice one. Updated the answer and jsFiddle to include this as well.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Classes and HTML `<span>` are your friends. Use them.

**HTML**

```
<p class="foo"><span class="bar">למרות הכל</span>its worth it</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo { font-family: Arial; }
p .bar { font-family: Helvetica; }
```

And now it is done.